# Reference not set to instance error

Tags: c#, object, reference

I am getting the error "reference not set to an instance of an object" when the following code occurs on startup:

```
  switch (Popup_Data_Type_ComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString())
            {
```

I am pretty sure that this error is occurring as Popup_Data_Type_ComboBox has not yet been created therefore its not possible to get the sting value. How Can I get around this problem?

Ok thanks a lot for all the help I threw in a check if Popup_Data_Type_ComboBox.SelectedItem == null and it now works fine

Comment: Create `Popup_Data_Type_ComboBox` before trying to access it.

Comment: this could be SelectedItem too tha equal to null. It's impossible to *answer* this question , without having more details about your app architecture.

Comment: You say "occurs on startup." There probably is not an item selected on startup

Comment: Either `Popup_Data_Type_ComboBox` or `Popup_Data_Type_ComboBox.SelectedItem` is `null`

Comment: where is the combo created? what is in the rest of the switch statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a check before the switch, assuming the code is in a method that just handles the `Popup_Data_Type_ComboBox.SelectionChanged`-event or the likes:

```
if (Popup_Data_Type_ComboBox == null 
    || Popup_Data_Type_ComboBox.SelectedIndex < 0)
{
    // Just return from the method, do nothing more.
    return;
}

switch (...)
{

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The most likely issue is that your combo box hasn't been created, or doesn't have a selected item.  In this case, you'd have to explicitly handle that:

```
if (Popup_Data_Type_ComboBox != null && Popup_Data_Type_ComboBox.SelectedItem != null)
{
    switch (Popup_Data_Type_ComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString())
    {
        //... 
    }
}
else
{
   // Do your initialization with no selected item here...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd verify first that Popup_Data_Type_ComboBox is instantiated, and then verify that an item is selected.  If you are running this on startup as you said, then it is likely no item is selected.  you can check with:

```
if(Popup_Data_Type_ComboBox.SelectedItem != null)
{
    switch (Popup_Data_Type_ComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString())
        {
            //.....
        }
 }
```